# How to recursively start multiple threads while killing the original thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am not sure how to convert a function I've written so that it will run as multiple threads concurrently in Java.

The function takes a root, which will be different for each thread that "splits off" at a given junction point (the if statement for this is within the function, each newly-created thread should be able to split off in the future as well, at the next junction).

I want all threads to die once they reach the target, but the "while" loop for checking whether they've reached the end is also within the function.

Basically, I want the function to be able to run multiple times concurrently, with a modified starting point each time, and for the "original" thread to be killed off before splitting.

I also can't extend Thread because I'm already extending another class, so I'm trying to do it by implementing Runnable.

Here is the class (the parent classes work fine so I don't think I need to post them):

```
public class Multithreaded extends ParentClass implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
         executeThread(modelThreaded, new HashMap<>());
    }

    private final Set<Tile> VISITED = new HashSet<>();
    private Grid modelThreaded; //to be able to update the root?

    public Multithreaded() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected int runPathfinder(Grid model, List<Tile> path) {
        HashMap<Tile, Integer> tileData = new HashMap<>();
        this.modelThreaded = model;
        this.executeThread(model, tileData);

        int cost = tileData.get(model.getTarget()) - 1;

        this.statistics.setPathFound(true, cost);
        this.painter.drawPath(path, model);

        return cost;
    }

    private void executeThread(Grid model, HashMap<Tile, Integer> tileData) {

        // Keeps track of visited tiles
        VISITED.add(model.getRoot());

        //start at the root
        Tile currentTile = model.getRoot();
        List<Tile> posNeighbors = model.getTileNeighbors(currentTile);
        List<Tile> validNeighbors = new ArrayList<>();

        int DEFAULT_DISTANCE = 1;
        tileData.put(model.getRoot(), DEFAULT_DISTANCE);
        int iteration = 0;

        while (!isVisited(model.getTarget())) {

            iteration++;
            posNeighbors.clear();
            validNeighbors.clear();
            posNeighbors = model.getTileNeighbors(currentTile);
            validNeighbors = getForward(posNeighbors);

            //debugging
            System.out.println("Valid Neighbors for currentTile ("
                    + currentTile.getX() + ", " + currentTile.getY() + "): ");
            for (Tile validNeighbor : validNeighbors) {
                System.out.println(validNeighbor.getX() + ", " + validNeighbor.getY());
            }

            // tries to split along junctions into multithreads
            // tries to kill mouse if there's a dead end
            if (validNeighbors.size() > 0) {
                for (Tile validNeighbor : validNeighbors) {
                    currentTile = validNeighbor;
                    // want to create a new thread for each validNeighbor here, but with
                    // a small change: the root changes to the current validNeighbor
                    model.setRoot(validNeighbor);
                    Runnable runnable = new Multithreaded();
                    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
                    thread.start();
                }
            }
            //attempt to kill/stop current thread if there are no more options left for that thread
            else {
                break;
            }


            VISITED.add(currentTile);
            tileData.put(currentTile, DEFAULT_DISTANCE + iteration);

        }
    

private List<Tile> getForward(List<Tile> posNeighbors) {
        List<Tile> validNeighbors = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Tile posNeighbor : posNeighbors) {
            if (posNeighbor != null && !posNeighbor.isWall()
                && !isVisited(posNeighbor)) {
                validNeighbors.add(posNeighbor);
            }
        }
        return validNeighbors;
    }

    private boolean isVisited(Tile posNeighbor) {
        for (Tile visitedTile : VISITED) {
            if (visitedTile == posNeighbor) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want the threads to keep going unless:

1. one of them encounters the target (model.getTarget()) or
2. it reaches a point where there are 0 validNeighbors.

When there's 1 validNeighbor for a thread, it should stay singular and proceed along that path until it either reaches another junction or a dead end (getForward returns only the unvisited neighbors)

So, when a thread encounters a junction (2 validNeighbors), it should split into two and kill the original thread (stopping its execution of executeThread, which is why I put a break in there), with one thread for each direction, and continue running the algorithm. With my current code, it runs down the path correctly, but doesn't split into different threads and doesn't stop running when it encounters a dead end.

What would be the best way to get this to run? Am I correct in putting executeThread() in run(), or is there somewhere else I should be putting it? I've tried just doing runnable.run() instead of Thread thread and thread.start(), but that doesn't seem to help. I'm really not sure what to do here, I feel like I'm missing something obvious...

EDIT: runPathfinder is the function called by the parent classes in order for all of this code to run

Comment: Basically, you want each tread to invoke the next one, recursively, until a certain stop condition is met. Is that correct ?  What resources are shared between the threads ?  `runPathfinder` is not used in the code posted. Please minimize the code to support yhr question (only) see [mre]

Comment: @c0der Apologies -- I'll edit my post to mention that runPathfinder is basically the "main" function of the code (it gets called by the main class to be run). If you think it'd help, I could edit the post to add the part of the code where it gets called?
Also yes, I want each thread to invoke the next one, but I want to make sure two threads are made from one thread at a junction point... And that a thread will completely stop if it reaches a dead end.

Comment: _" What resources are shared between the threads ?"_

Comment: Between the threads, I think it's just the VISITED hash set, tileData, and the model with the same target but a different root (I tried to do this through modelThreaded).  Is there anything else I should be sharing between the threads? Also, should I move the `VISITED.add(currentTile)` line up before the `thread.start()` or does it not matter? Should I add a `break()` after the `thread.start()`? Is using break() the right thing in this case, to end an instance of a thread of executeThread()?

Comment: You'd better be able to simplify, abstract your problem and provide a minimal and reproducible code. Otherwise, trying to understand the problem can take a lot of time, let alone help you solve it

Comment: Apologies! I didn't see that you had added an answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)<sup>(1)</sup> reproduces the multi-threading functionality required.

Each node (state / tile) is represented by an integer.
`getTileNeighbors` returns 3 random neighbors. 
All thread share a synchronized `visited` collection, and should stop after `target` was added to `visited`.
(copy-paste the entire code to Main.java and run)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main   {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Multithreaded(0, 20)).start();
    }
}

class Multithreaded  implements Runnable {

    // Synchronized Set (shared between threads)
    private static final Set<Integer> visited = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Integer>());
    private final int root, target;

    //root and target assumed >=0
    public Multithreaded(int root, int target) {
        this.root = root;
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        executeThread(root);
    }

    private void executeThread(int root) {

        visited.add(root);
        System.out.println("New thread, root="+ root);
        while (!isStopConditionMet()) {

            List<Integer> neighbors = getTileNeighbors(root);
            //todo if  neighbors is empty break out of the while loop
            
            for (Integer neighbor : neighbors) {

                if(! visited.add(neighbor)) {
                    continue; //skip is already visited
                }

                Runnable runnable = new Multithreaded(neighbor, target);
                Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
                thread.start();
            }
        }
    }

    //returns a list o 3 random numbers between 0-target (inclusive)
    //to represent 3 random neighbors
    private List<Integer> getTileNeighbors(int currentTile) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int maxValue = target +1;
        return Arrays.asList(rnd.nextInt(maxValue), rnd.nextInt(maxValue), rnd.nextInt(maxValue));
    }

    private boolean isStopConditionMet() {
        return visited.contains(target);
    }
}
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> mre should demonstrate the problem to be solved, and not a specific application.